# Статичные шейдеры

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Я плохо знаком с шейдерами, но как я понял, они работают в реалтайме, но вот если у меня шейдер который должен один раз изменить конкретную текстуру и что бы она всегда оставалась такой.. получается шейдер во всю работает, но на экране ничего не меняется, ибо текстура меняется по одному и тому же алгоритму.

Возможно ли как то шейдер запустить, что бы он задал параметры изображению, а потом поставить на паузу, что бы дальше ничего не обрабатывал?

Comment: Включить шейдер, нарисовать требуемую картинку на сюрфейс, выключить шейдер, рисовать сюрфейс?

Comment: @D-side не совсем понимаю что такое сюрфейс, можешь рассказать по подробнее?

Comment: Не знаю, как это называется у вас в доступных графических API, но это фрагмент видеопамяти, на котором можно рисовать вещи. В разных местах встречал термины surface и framebuffer.

Comment: @D-side c framebuffer понятнее) Способ в принципе подходит, но жаль с SKShader не получится реализовать...